# Using footmisc's para option in lscape

Tags: footnotes, incompatibility, landscape, footmisc

I'd like to use the `para` option of the package `footmisc` to make a compact list of (short) footnotes. This works well for regular pages, but stops working when I switch to landscape mode. Does anyone know how to make this work in landscape mode?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape} 

At vero\footnote{One.} eos\footnote{Two.} et\footnote{Three.} accusamus\footnote{Four.} et iusto odio ...

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the order in which you load the packages:

```
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lscape}
```

If you are using pdflatex, you could use [pdflscape](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdflscape) instead of `lscape`.

Comment: Thx! That was easy :)